# How to merge paths (NSString) in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Imagine you have two paths.

http://myserver.com/path1/path2 + /path1/path2/cache/image1.jpg = http://myserver.com/path1/path2/cache/image1.jpg

Both path strings could have more or less path components.

So what I'm asking is how to find the equal part in the strings and then remove that part from one of the strings?

Comment: Equal part to left side or right side?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This should do for you:

```
NSString* path1 = @"http://myserver.com/path1/path2";
NSString* path2 = @"/path1/path2/cache/image1.jpg";

NSMutableArray* path1Components = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[path1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]];
NSMutableArray* path2Components = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[path2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]];
[path2Components removeObjectAtIndex:0];

if ([path1Components containsObject:[path2Components objectAtIndex:0]]) {

    NSUInteger objectIndex = [path1Components indexOfObject:[path2Components objectAtIndex:0]];

    [path1Components removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(objectIndex, [path1Components count]-objectIndex)];

    [path1Components addObjectsFromArray:path2Components];

    NSString* mergedPath = [path1Components componentsJoinedByString:@"/"];

    NSLog(@"%@",mergedPath);

}
```

Comment: This won't work for string: `NSString* path1 = @"http://myserver.com/path1/path2";` and `NSString* path2 = @"/path1/cache/image1.jpg";`

Comment: @Nekto did you try with your sample strings? With your strings my algorithm produces http://myserver.com/path1/cache/image1.jpg What output you are expecting?

Comment: Of course, http://myserver.com/path1/path2/path1/cache/image1.jpg. There are no "path2" in `path2`

Comment: I don't think OP wants a path like ../path1/path2/path1/... In my understanding one has to find where path2 branches from path1 and concatenate there to make it as an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

You have no idea whether the "equal" parts are really equal or not.  It's not uncommon to have, eg, paths like .../part1/part1/part1/...

For the mechanics of dealing with the paths, though, NSString has some nice methods -- lastPathComponent, stringByAppendindPathComponent, pathComponents, pathWithComponents, etc.

Comment: Yes you are correct, that is not uncommon. But in my situation that will never happen. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
- (NSString *)mergeStringsPrefix:(NSString *)prefix suffix:(NSString *)suffix
{
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", prefix];

    NSArray *prefixComponents = [prefix pathComponents];
    NSArray *suffixComponents = [suffix pathComponents];

    if ([prefixComponents count] == 0) return [string retain]; 
    int rootIndex = [suffixComponents indexOfObject:@"/"];
    int index = 1;
    if (rootIndex == NSNotFound || rootIndex != 0) index = 0;

    int startIndex = [prefixComponents indexOfObject:[suffixComponents objectAtIndex:index]];
    if (startIndex == NSNotFound) return nil;

    if ([suffixComponents count] - index < [prefixComponents count] - startIndex) return nil;

    // fing length and check merge compatability
    BOOL equalParts = YES;
    for (int i=startIndex; i<[prefixComponents count] && equalParts; i++, index++)
    {
        NSString *el1 = [prefixComponents objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *el2 = [suffixComponents objectAtIndex:index];

        if ([el1 compare:el2] != NSOrderedSame) equalParts = NO;
    }
    if (!equalParts) return nil;
    // merge
    for (int i=index; i<[suffixComponents count]; i++)
    {
        string = [string stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", [suffixComponents objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    return [string retain];
}
```

Comment: I think I'd just use hasSuffix or hasPrefix, after selecting a segment of the other string.  But that assumes I'd do this at all, which I wouldn't -- it's a bad idea.

Comment: Thx Nekto, great way of doing it. I'm going with Saran's solution since it's soo simple :)

Comment: You make wrong decision. Just test that function. It works only for concrete example. For example, try this strings: `NSString* path1 = @"http://myserver.com/path1/path2";` and `NSString* path2 = @"/path1/cache/image1.jpg";`. You will get right result with my function and wrong with Saran's.